# Unable to log in to ADFS using FireFox 30.0

Tags: firefox, authentication, adfs

I try to login to ADFS using Firefox 30.0. SP sends auth request. ADFS shows error:

> Server Error
>   401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. 
>   You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Other browsers and other versions of firefox are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox disabled NTLMv1 authentication by security reasons since version 30.0. It recommends to upgrade NTLM to version 2. But NTLMv2 is supported only on Windows platform.
Read https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=973640

**Workarounds:**

1) To login using ADFS with NTLMv1 and FF 30 and higher you should to configure FF. 
Open settings page **about:config**.  Set *network.negotiate-auth.allow-insecure-ntlm-v1* = *true*.

2) To don't use NTLMv1 in ADFS you can change the local authentication type to "Forms-based authentication".

See http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1600.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-change-the-local-authentication-type.aspx